# Why does nothing happen when it gets to the ratio question 1 method c#

Tags: c#

I'm working on an assignment for school and nothing happens when it gets to the RatioQuestion1 Method. I have tried to see the difference between it and the other methods that do similar things (ie say text, does thing with text) and nothing works. Am I just doing something wrong?

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Get ready for a *MATH SHOWDOWN*");

            Console.Write("If you would like a tutorial on how this works say \"1\", If you would like to go ahead and start say \"2\", And if you would like to see credits say '3'");
            int openingprompt = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            if (openingprompt == 2) 
            {
                FindProblem();
                
            }
            else if (openingprompt == 1)
            {

            }    

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        static void RatioQuestion1()
        {
            Console.Write("A math club has 25 members, of which 11 are boys and the rest are girls. What is the ratio of males to all club members");
            int ratioQ1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine(ratioQ1);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        static void FindProblem()
        {
            Console.Write("If you would like a ratio problem say '1'");
            int Problemtype = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            if (Problemtype == 1)
            {
                FindRatioProblem();

            }
            else if (Problemtype == 2)
            {

            }

        }
        static void FindRatioProblem()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ratio question coming up!");
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int problemnum = rnd.Next(1);

            if (problemnum == 1)
            {
                RatioQuestion1();
            }
```

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "nothing happens"?  When you step through the code in a debugger, what specific operation produces an unexpected result?  What is that result?

Comment: I think it's here `Random rnd = new Random();
            int problemnum = rnd.Next(1);` how random is random? do you know? It would probably always be `0`   try `new Random(DateTime.UtcNow.Milliseconds)`

Answer (score 1):

It's because [`Random.Next()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.next?view=netcore-3.1#System_Random_Next_System_Int32_) has an exclusive upperbound, so when you call `Next(1)`, it's taking a random number between `0` and `1-1`... which is `0`, so the if condition is always `false`. To quote the documentation:

> Returns a non-negative random integer that is **less than the specified maximum.**

Change your code to:

```
int problemnum = rnd.Next(2);
```

and it'll return either `0` or `1`, so the condition will sometimes evaluate to `true`.